# Cannot call user ID when slash command sent in pycord

Tags: python, pycord

I am trying to create an intuitive discord bot that uses pycord as its library to be able to allow people to communicate to my bot & my features will be using slash commands. When I am trying to grab the ID of the user who sent the slash command, it results in the userId not being printed. Here is my code:

```
TOKEN = env.token
#Temporary token.

import discord
from discord.ext import commands
bot = commands.Bot()
print("Logging all data.")
#Login
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"{bot.user} is online.")

#Register for beta
@bot.slash_command(name="register",description="Register for beta features.  ")
async def register_beta(ctx): 
    await ctx.respond("Paragon has given you access to beta features.", ephemeral=True)
    print(ctx.author.id())
bot.run(TOKEN)
```

and when I try to launch the bot & run the slash command, it gives me this error:

```
Ignoring exception in command register:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/Work/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/commands/core.py", line 110, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(arg)
  File "/home/runner/Work/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/commands/core.py", line 774, in _invoke
    await self.callback(ctx, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 16, in register_beta
    print(ctx.author.id())
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/Work/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/bot.py", line 768, in process_application_commands
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/runner/Work/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/commands/core.py", line 306, in invoke
    await injected(ctx)
  File "/home/runner/Work/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/commands/core.py", line 116, in wrapped
    raise ApplicationCommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.commands.errors.ApplicationCommandInvokeError: Application Command raised an exception: TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

I am using pycord version 2.0.0b4. I couldn't seemingly find any documentation for this issue.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask], as well as reading the error message. See where it shows the code, `print(ctx.author.id())`, and then complains `'int' object is not callable`? What do you think this line of code should do? In particular, what do you think the `ctx.author.id` part should do? Does that give you a function that can be called? Or does it give you an integer? (If you aren't sure, **read the documentation**.) So, does it make sense to put `()` after that? (Hint: what do you think should happen if you try `1()`?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`id` is not a method. It is an attribute. Change `print(ctx.author.id())` to `print(ctx.author.id)`

Comment: Please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and try to resolve problems like this by *checking the documentation*. Even if you don't know where the main page is for the documentation, you can e.g. try putting `discord.py documentation ctx.author.id` [into a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=discord.py+documentation+ctx.author.id).